# basic python for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am new to python could someone tell me what is the problem with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
nl=[] 
for x in range(1500, 2700):
     i=0
     if (x%7==0) and (x%5==0):
         nl[i]=x
     i=i+1
print (','.join(nl))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the zero-length list problem mentioned in other answers. You set `i = 0` at every iteration of your loop. So you always change the same element (the first one) of your list.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `n` to be a zero-length `list`, but you write to (presumed) elements beyond the end of the list.

One way to fix this is to change the assignment of `n` to:

```
n = [None]*1200
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set arbitrary indexes into a 0 length list.

Use a list, and append:

```
# nl[i]=x <- this won't work
nl.append(x)
```

Since you don't seem to use the actual index when you print, this should work.  Be advised, you will need to use

```
print(",".join(map(str, nl)))
```

as join won't work on ints.

If you do need the index, I would suggest using a dictionary.

```
nl = {}
low = 1500 
high = 2700
for x in range(low, high):
     if (x % 7 == 0) and (x % 5 ==0):
         nl[x-low] = x
print(','.join(map(str, nl.values())))
```

**NOTE** the values in this case won't be sorted.  If you want them to be then you could sort them

```
print(','.join(map(str, sorted(nl.values()))))
```

Also, you can now iterate the indexes and values (even in sorted order) with

```
for index, value in sorted(nl.items()):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nl=[] 
for x in range(1500, 2700):

    if (x%7==0) and (x%5==0):
       nl.append(str(x))

print (','.join(nl))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a index you can try using the **append** method in list which would be really helpful in this case . Try the following

```
nl=[]
for x in range(1500,2700):
if x%7==0 and x%5==0 :
    m.append(x)
print(nl)
```

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this program instead:

```
nl=[]
for x in range(1500, 2700):
    if (x%7==0) and (x%5==0):
        nl.append(x)
print nl
```

It works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[1505, 1540, 1575, 1610, 1645, 1680, 1715, 1750, 1785, 1820, 1855, 1890, 1925, 1960, 1995, 2030, 2065, 2100, 2135, 2170, 2205, 2240, 2275, 2310, 2345, 2380, 2415, 2450, 2485, 2520, 2555, 2590, 2625, 2660, 2695]
>>>
```

Problems of your code:

1. You are trying to assign values to a zero-length list (i.e. to `nl`). You must use `append()` method to append its length.
2. You want to join integer numbers in a list with `,` character. You don't need it at all. print the list itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've set `i = 0` inside the for loop. Instead, set it outside and increment.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in Python, you can use a so-called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the same result in one line:

```
nl = [x for x in range(1500, 2700) if (x%7==0) and (x%5==0)]
```

This provides a list of `int`. To print it, you need to convert the `int` to `string`:

```
print(','.join(map(str, nl)))
```

Or you can directly create a list of strings:

```
nl = [str(x) for x in range(1500, 2700) if (x%7==0) and (x%5==0)]
print(','.join(nl))
```

If all you want is printing it, everything can be done in one single line:

```
print(','.join(str(x) for x in range(1500, 2700) if (x%7==0) and (x%5==0)))
```